# Is the Warhammer Fantasy world actually Earth?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

There are clearly some strong similarities between the Warhammer Fantasy map and Earth.

These are mentioned here, amongst many other places

http://warhammeronline.wikia.com/wiki/The_World_of_Warhammer

However, no-one seemed to mention the reason for this similarity.

Looking for either (or both) an in universe and an out of universe answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No

The Warhammer Fantasy world is not Earth, if by that we mean it is **the past or future of a world with a recorded history essentially identical to our own.**

1. Warhammer has countries with cultures highly similar to countries in our world. **This is actually a point *against* it being Earth**, since it is rather improbable that, for example, a country rather similar to Austria would arise twice in essentially the same way. Fantasy counterpart cultures of Warhammer Fantasy include:

   - The Empire bears obvious similarities to Austria, Germany, and the Austro-Hungarian Empire. Naming schemes are fairly obviously German-derived. The Empire  has former provinces such as Drakwald (basically the German Drachenwald). People have German names everywhere you look.
   - Nippon is literally "Japan" in Japanese.
   - Cathay is an old word for China.
   - Albion is the old name of Britain

But the events that occur in the novels and games **could not have taken place when those names and cultures were in currency in our world**. The entire game is also set at a Renaissance level of technology, but history has no record of dwarves, elves, or vampires living in Renaissance Europe, nor the worship of Chaos Gods.

Another  thing, which precludes Warhammer Fantasy being set in the *past* of Earth, is the End Times, which [resulted in the Age of Sigmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warhammer_Age_of_Sigmar). Basically, the entire Warhammer Fantasy world was completely destroyed:

> Following **the destruction of the Warhammer World by the forces of
>   Chaos**, Sigmar floated through outer space, clinging to the core of the
>   Old world.

**Warhammer Fantasy may, on the other hand, be conceived of as an *alternate Earth*: a world with an entirely different history, but significant similarities to our own.**

Comment: Agreed. WHFRP and it's setting were heavily influenced by the books of Michael Moorcock, in which several alternate Earths are depicted as part of the Multiverse. I'm not saying the WHFRP world is supposed to be part of Moorcock's Multiverse, but just that it appears to be intended as an alternate version of Earth in the same way.

Comment: This is a really interesting answer +1

Comment: The entire game is also set at a Renaissance level of technology, but history has no record of dwarves, elves, or vampires living in Renaissance Europe, nor the worship of Chaos Gods.  [Citation needed]

Answer (score 2):

Warhammer Fantasy is unlikely to be set in Earth's **past**, but the [Blood Bowl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_Bowl) games, sometimes set in the same universe (although, around 3rd edition, Word of God changed to it being "[similar to, but definitely not the same as, the *Warhammer* world](http://www.midgardbb.com/JervisRules/Jervis_Talk_08172005.mp3)"), are implied to be in Earth's future, with the rules being adapted from the discovered sacred documents of the deity, Nuffle (NFL) from the land of Amorika.

Answer (score 0):

**YES (or deliberately looking as one)**

It definitely looks that way, with some nations and geographical features being virtually the same.

If we don't take into account the Warhammer 40000 lore (which includes both the Earth and Warhammer Fantasy settings as two separate planets - where the latter could be fashioned after Earth by the "old ones"), then the creators most likely pulled "a Howard" here, where the creator of Conan the Barbarian and Kul the Conqueror and basically the father of the whole sword and sorcery genre placed his fantasy world into a super ancient version of Earth with distorted geography and eerily similar names for nations and their characteristics, which would be in accordance with the statement that history repeats itself.

Comment: While there was a popular theory saying that Warhammer Fantasy and 40k are in the same universe (and other saying i.e. that Sigmar is a missing primarch), Games Workshop officially denied that. While it is obvious that Old World supposed to look like Earth, it is definitely not our planet.