# Is the Old World connected to the 40k universe?

Tags: warhammer-40k, warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar

Is the End Times connected to 40k or is it a complete different story? Because the Old World is hardly High-Terra and the corruption that Archaon brought is not the purity of High-Terra.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll delete the question since it's a duplicate

Comment: Also related: [Is the Warhammer Fantasy world actually Earth?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129169/is-the-warhammer-fantasy-world-actually-earth?rq=1).

Comment: No need to delete it. We can just close. Having duplicates that cover additional search terms can actually be helpful. It’ll get autodeleted if it doesn’t get any upvotes anyway.

Comment: Sure do, close it

Comment: I think the wikia blog puts it quite well http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:27851

Comment: I've been following fantasy/40k since the late 80'si enjoy watch people suddenly figure out gat there might be a connection.  Over and over.  :)

Comment: @bacon the op says himself that that's "wild speculation" so it does not answer the question as much as the duplicate